# CiviCRM edit history for different users

Tags: civicontribute, admin

Is there a way to find out when an account signs into the CiviCRM admin panel and edits something. Specifically I am looking for the person who changed a price field. We're using Joomla with Civi.

Logging was not turned on

Answer (score 2):

If you have logging switched on you should be able to find this in the log tables. If you do not have logging switched on I do not think you can find this.

You can check your logging at Adminster>System Setting>Misc (Undelete..........

Comment: Unfortunately, logging was not turned on